# C - How to count words in a txt file?

Tags: c

So I'm supposed to count how many words there are in a txt file with multiple lines, and words are defined as a continuous sequence of letters (a through z, and A through Z) and the apostrophe seperated by any character outside these ranges.

I've got what I think looks right, but the wordcount keeps on coming out wrong. Does anyone see anything weird about my code?

Please ignore the linecount and charcount, as they are working properly. I tried counting the spaces between the words, with 32 being the ASCII code for a space.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int c;
int charcount = 0;
int wordcount = 1;
int linecount = 0;

while (c != EOF)
{
    c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF)
        break;
    if (c == 10)
        linecount++;

    charcount++;

    if (c == 32)
        wordcount++;

}

printf ("%d %d %d\n", charcount, wordcount, linecount);
return 0;

}
```

So for example, one of the txt files says:

```
Said Hamlet to Ophelia,
I'll draw a sketch of thee,
What kind of pencil shall I use?
2B or not 2B?
```

The word count here is 21, but I get a wordcount of 18. I tried counting in the number of "/n" and it works for this test, but it fails for the next test.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your code, only the space character increases the number of words, and so words at the end of a line are not counted.

Comment: wordcount = number of whitespace characters + 1. (If your file ends with a newline, even adding 1 is not necessary).

Comment: You should just step through in a debugger and figure it out. This site is not a debugging service.

Comment: BTW, don't use 10 and 32 as hard character codes. C does not mandate ASCII/UTF-8, and what's worse, they are hard to read. Also, `while (c != EOF)` is redundant, it could just be `while (1)`. Or `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` if you like to disturb readability freaks (like me).

Comment: @H2CO3 Its not so easy. If you have 2,3 etc consecutive spaces you still count words

Comment: @valter That's right, but I don't think it applies in this case (normally, sane text files are separated by one WS character).

Comment: @H2CO3 I now this trick. Thats why i said its not so easy. In this case anyway it applies nicely.

Comment: @H2CO3 common counter-examples include “two spaces after sentence-final punctuation,” indented block quotes, trailing whitespace on lines, paragraph breaks with double-newlines, and teletype/network/DOS text with CR+LF pairs on each line

Comment: @BRPocock also, the French people use WS before punctuation : like this. (and it's not even consistent, only the colon, semi-colon, question mark and exclamation point are written in this strange manner. Comma and full stop aren't.) - as to DOS/Windows with CR;LF: I intentionally wrote *"sane":* Windows/DOS don't count as such in my read :P

Comment: Agreed DOS≠sanity, but SMTP, HTTP, et all still think they're on teletypes, too, so we'll see #\Return in files for quite a while after the ghosts of CP/M are forgotten. This is where I would suggest matching `\b(\w+)\b` or `$(wc)` but I'm curious to see an answer to this that matches `wc` on any non-trivial corpus …

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a simple FSM coded in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

enum {INITIAL,WORD,SPACE};

int main()
{
  int c;
  int state = INITIAL;
  int wcount = 0;

  c = getchar();
  while (c != EOF)
  {
    switch (state)
    {
      case INITIAL: wcount = 0;
                    if (isalpha(c) || c=='\'')
                    {
                       wcount++;
                       state = WORD;
                    }
                    else
                       state = SPACE;
                    break;

      case WORD:    if (!isalpha(c) && c!='\'')
                       state = SPACE;
                    break;

      case SPACE:   if (isalpha(c) || c=='\'')
                    {
                       wcount++;
                       state = WORD;
                    }
    }
    c = getchar();
  }
  printf ("%d words\n", wcount);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whoa this is advanced haha. But thanks so much! I know where I went wrong with my code now.

Comment: `isalpha` -> `isalnum`, if (question for the OP) a number is *also* a word. It works for the example because `2B` contains at least a single letter, but the digit is not considered and does not change the state to something useful.

Comment: According to his question, a digit is not part of a word: "words are defined as a continuous sequence of letters (a through z, and A through Z) and the apostrophe"

Comment: @Jongware: digit is considered a separator character, so when it is read, the state changes to SPACE

Comment: BTW: why the negative?

Comment: Ah, you are right. You could do with just 2 states, though, and only increase `wordcount` on a *change* to WORD state. (Dunno why the -1. Perhaps your solution is too different from what the OP tried.)

Comment: Well... that's exactly what I'm doing: increase `wordcount` when there is a transition from `SPACE` to `WORD`. The `INITIAL` state is there because I don't know at the beginning if my text begins with a word or not. Moving the initial comparison out of the loop is equivalent to move it into the loop, enclosed in a state that only occurs once, at the beginning. It makes the whole thing more clear to me, and allows for easier maintenance, if I eventually have to add more states to differentiate words from numbers, or count newlines, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Include ctype.h and then change

```
if (c == 32)
    wordcount++
```

to

```
if (isspace(c))
    wordcount++
```

Words are separated by spaces, tabs, and line characters.